# How to check if two strings contain the same letters?

Tags: php, string, match

```
$textone = "pate"; //$_GET
$texttwo = "tape";
$texttre = "tapp";

if ($textone ??? $texttwo) {
echo "The two strings contain the same letters";
}
if ($textone ??? $texttre) {
echo "The two strings NOT contain the same letters";
}
```

What `if` statement am I looking for?

Comment: Do you want to know if two strings contain the same characters, in the same order (the strings are the same), or do you want to know if any character from one string is in the other string?  Can you show the expected result for the strings you have provided?

Comment: i want to know if all character from one string is in the other string

Comment: How about `tap` and `tapp` - what would you expect the result to be?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suppose a solution could be to, considering the two following variables :

```
$textone = "pate";
$texttwo = "tape";
```

**1.** First, split the strings, to get two arrays of letters :

```
$arr1 = preg_split('//', $textone, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$arr2 = preg_split('//', $texttwo, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Note that, as pointed out by @Mike in his comment, instead of using [`preg_split()`](http://www.php.net/preg_split) like I first did, for such a situation, one would be better off using [`str_split()`](http://www.php.net/str_split) :

```
$arr1 = str_split($textone);
$arr2 = str_split($texttwo);
```

**2.** Then, sort those array, so the letters are in alphabetical order :

```
sort($arr1);
sort($arr2);
```

**3.** After that, implode the arrays, to create *words* where all letters are in alphabetical order :

```
$text1Sorted = implode('', $arr1);
$text2Sorted = implode('', $arr2);
```

**4.** And, finally, compare those two *words* :

```
if ($text1Sorted == $text2Sorted) {
    echo "$text1Sorted == $text2Sorted";
}
else {
    echo "$text1Sorted != $text2Sorted";
}
```

---

Turning this idea into a comparison function would give you the following portion of code :

```
function compare($textone, $texttwo) {
    $arr1 = str_split($textone);
    $arr2 = str_split($texttwo);

    sort($arr1);
    sort($arr2);

    $text1Sorted = implode('', $arr1);
    $text2Sorted = implode('', $arr2);

    if ($text1Sorted == $text2Sorted) {
        echo "$text1Sorted == $text2Sorted<br />";
    }
    else {
        echo "$text1Sorted != $text2Sorted<br />";
    }
}
```

And calling that function on your two *words* :

```
compare("pate", "tape");
compare("pate", "tapp");
```

Would get you the following result :

```
aept == aept
aept != appt
```

Comment: what the hell? what is difference between === and yours?

Comment: @genesis `'ab'` and `'ba'` contain the same letters, so my `compare()` function says they are the same. On the other hand, `'ab'` and `'ba'` are not equal, so `var_dump("ab" === "ba");` will get you `boolean false`

Comment: @Mike shame on me, I had totally forgotten about that function ; thanks for your comment, I will edit my answer to point out that str_split could be used to :-)

Answer (score -1):

use `===` and `!==`

```
if ($textone === $texttwo) {
    echo "The two strings contain the same letters";
}else{
    echo "The two strings NOT contain the same letters";
}
```

or

```
if ($textone === $texttwo) {
    echo "The two strings contain the same letters";
}

if ($textone !== $texttwo) {
    echo "The two strings NOT contain the same letters";
}
```