# PHP combinations of array elements

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, combinations

I want to generate all possible combination of array elements to fill a placeholder, the placeholder size could vary.

Let say I have array `$a = array(3, 2, 9, 7)` and placeholder size is `6`. I want to generate something like the following:

```
3,3,3,3,3,3
2,3,3,3,3,3
2,2,3,3,3,3
...........
...........
7,7,7,7,7,9
7,7,7,7,7,7
```

However `(2,3,3,3,3,3)` would be considered the same as `(3,2,3,3,3,3)` so the later one doesn't count.

Could anyone point me to the right direction? I know there is `Math_Combinatorics` `pear` package, but that one is only applicable to placeholder size `<= count($a)`.

**Edit**
I am thinking that this one is similar to bits string combination though with different number base

Comment: This is not quite logical, as for some combinations are arbitrary. It would depend on the preceding combinations to make out whether a new combination is legal or not. Though still doable off course.

Comment: what if `placeholder < count($a)` ?

Comment: sorry, wanted to give an answer. started in the wrong field.

Comment: @OfirBaruch: I knew it is. It will take too much time indeed. Will not give an answer. Sorry, haven't got that much time.

Comment: @nl-x because sometimes the placeholder may be bigger than `count($a)`

Comment: @LoekBergman What do you mean by taking too much time?

Comment: @user78431 that is not my question. I asked can placeholder be smaller than count($a) ?

Comment: For me to give you a working example. Your request requires elaborate programming. It is a nice puzzle, but not during day time hours while working.

Comment: Take a look on elementary algorithm as you can see in http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations_by_swapping

Answer (score 1):

I have no PHP source code for you but some sources that might help.

Some C code. Look at 2.1:
http://www.aconnect.de/friends/editions/computer/combinatoricode_g.html

Delphi code: [combination without repetition of N elements without use for..to..do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316479/combination-without-repetition-of-n-elements-without-use-for-to-do)

Wiki article [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)

Answer (score 0):

Well it took quit some time to figure this one out.

So i split the question into multiple parts

1.
I firsrt made an array with all the possible value options.

```
function create_all_array($placeholder, array $values)
{
    if ($placeholder <= 0) {
        return [];
    }

    $stack = [];
    $values = array_unique($values);

    foreach ($values as $value) {
        $stack[] = [
            'first' => $value,
            'childs' => create_all_array($placeholder - 1, $values)
        ];
    }

    return $stack;
}
```

2.
Then I made a function to stransform this massive amount of data into string (no check for uniques).

```
function string($values, $prefix = '')
{
    $stack = [];

    foreach($values as $value) {
        $sub_prefix = $prefix . $value['first'];

        if (empty($value['childs'])) {
            $stack[$sub_prefix] = (int)$sub_prefix;
        } else {
            $stack = array_merge($stack, string($value['childs'], $sub_prefix));
        }
    }

    return $stack;
}
```

3.
Then the hard part came. Check for duplicates. This was harder than expected, [but found some good anser to it and refactored it for my use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807864/how-to-check-if-two-strings-contain-the-same-letters).

```
function has_duplicate($string, $items)
{
    $explode = str_split ($string);
    foreach($items as $item) {
        $item_explode = str_split($item);

        sort($explode);
        $string = implode('',$explode);
        sort($item_explode);
        $item = implode($item_explode);

        if ($string == $item) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

4.
The last step was to combine the intel into a new funciton :P

```
function unique_string($placeholder, array $values)
{
    $stack = string(create_all_array($placeholder, $values));

    $check_stack = [];
    foreach($stack as $key => $item) {
        if (has_duplicate($item, $check_stack)) {
            unset($stack[$key]);
        }
        $check_stack[] = $item;
    }
    return $stack;
}
```

Now you can use it simple as followed

```
unique_string(3 /* amount of dept */, [1,2,3] /* keys */);
```

Ps the code is based for PHP5.4+, to convert to lower you need to change the `[]` to `array()` but I love the new syntax so sorry :P